# How can I compute a confidence interval on Cohen's d derived from a Tukey HSD contrast?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, tukey-hsd-test, cohens-d, lsmeans

**Question Background**

- Consider for example that I have some data arrayed as a 1-way (Group: A, B, C, D) between groups ANOVA.
- Consider further that I am interested in all possible pairwise contrasts of the means of each group, and that I want to control my error rate using Tukey's method for multiple comparisons.
- I can compute Cohen's $d$ for each contrast by dividing the mean difference by the square root of the model mean square error (pooled standard deviation)

**Question**

- How do I compute a confidence interval for this computation of Cohen's $d$?
- Usually I would use the method implemented by `psych::d.ci` or `MBESS::ci.smd`, but I'm not sure if these are providing accurate confidence intervals?

---

**Reproducible example in R**

- Toy data

```
data.frame(
          id = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
                        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
                        34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
                        50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60)),
       group = factor(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A",
                        "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",
                        "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",
                 "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",
                 "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D")),
          dv = c(116.9124522, 116.3721482, 95.03599571, 77.85024254,
                 84.53953315, 133.2504244, 99.83446571, 90.4640921,
                 96.13462834, 95.01707218, 96.78071497, 106.6069644, 95.92937522,
                 108.1734407, 118.7583455, 132.4623615, 119.066997, 104.6340656,
                 119.0042505, 106.5762639, 158.7926784, 103.3239485, 129.1846327,
                 114.7464756, 116.9962989, 106.3731085, 118.4781824, 136.9467748,
                 112.9751684, 126.7877026, 118.9720475, 86.49296151, 67.64059426,
                 98.89821874, 87.51737685, 99.91105598, 110.3385682, 103.4132733,
                 83.06624327, 112.5256676, 83.63994022, 105.6656707, 105.8091834,
                 107.9573785, 112.3731383, 69.74987985, 53.39494331, 24.56946779,
                 41.96801364, 58.4781887, 65.86905785, 29.70303444, 46.95819259,
                 38.83602144, 59.25075588, 33.34588524, 40.7039391, 64.76264007,
                 57.19752076, 57.15540306)
)
```

- Run the ANOVA

```
model = 
  dat %>% 
  afex::aov_ez(
    id = "id", 
    dv = "dv",
    data = ., 
    between = "group", 
    anova_table = list(es = c("pes", "ges")))
```

- Compute marginal means

```
emm = emmeans(model, spec = ~group)
```

- Compute Tukey contrasts
- Compute Cohen's $d$ by dividing estimates by model pooled standard deviation

```
tuk_contrasts = 
  emm %>% 
  contrast(., interaction = "pairwise", adjust = "tukey") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(d = .$estimate/sigma(model$aov))
```

- How do I now compute a confidence interval on $d$?

Comment: My inclination is that, since you are using estimates and standard deviations from the model, that one approach would be to pass the whole procedure through a bootstrap process to produce the confidence intervals. This is relatively easy with the `boot` package.

Comment: Bootstrap confidence intervals are a great idea - thanks! But I'm still curious - is there no exact confidence interval method for a Tukey HSD contrast?